# Duplicate & switch case

Tags: code-golf, string

The goal is, having taken a string as input, duplicate each latin letter and "toggle" its case (i.e. uppercase becomes lowercase and vice-versa).

Example inputs & outputs:

```
Input      Output
bad        bBaAdD
Nice       NniIcCeE
T e S t    Tt eE Ss tT
s E t      sS Ee tT
1!1!1st!   1!1!1sStT!
n00b       nN00bB     
(e.g.)     (eE.gG.)
H3l|@!     Hh3lL|@!
```

The input consists of printable ASCII symbols.

*You shouldn't duplicate non-latin letters, numbers, special chars.*

Comment: This is a very nice, simple-but-not-trivial challenge.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Jelly, 5 bytes

```
żŒsQ€
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=xbzFknNR4oKs&input=&args=J1QgZSBTIHQn)

#### How it works

```
żŒsQ€  Main link. Argument: s (string)

 Œs    Yield s with swapped case.
ż      Zip s with the result.
   Q€  Unique each; deduplicate each pair of characters.
```

Answer (score 17):

## Python, <s>56</s> 54 bytes

```python
lambda s:''.join(c+c.swapcase()*c.isalpha()for c in s)
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/fj1Ge9).

Comment: Dang! Out golfed me by 4 bytes...

Comment: How does this maintain the non-letter characters? I'd think they'd show up as empty strings.

Comment: @atlasologist As you can see on Ideone, they do not. `*` has higher precedence than `+`, so it only affects the `c` with swapped case.

Comment: Ohh, okay, I didn't think of it like that. Nice.

Answer (score 16):

## JavaScript ES6, <s>70</s> <s>68</s> <s>66</s> 64 bytes

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@Kevin Lau - not Kenny](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/kevin-lau-not-kenny)*

*Saved 2 bytes thanks to [@Cᴏɴᴏʀ O'Bʀɪᴇɴ](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31957/c%E1%B4%8F%C9%B4%E1%B4%8F%CA%80-ob%CA%80%C9%AA%E1%B4%87%C9%B4)*

```
s=>s.replace(/[A-Z]/gi,l=>l+l[`to${l<"a"?"Low":"Upp"}erCase`]())
```

### Explanation

This uses a really hacky:

```
l[`to${l<"a"?"Low":"Upp"}erCase`]()
```

which ungolfed is:

```
l[`to${
   l < "a" ?
   "Low" : 
   "Upp"
}erCase`]()
```

Basically `l < "a"` checks if the code point of the letter is less then the code point of `a` (therefore being an uppercase letter). If it is it'll do `to + Low + erCase` which becomed `l['toLowerCase']()` and makes the character lowercase. `` ` `` quotes allow string formatting so essentially you can think of:

```
`to${l < "a" ?"Low" : "Upp"}erCase`
```

as: `"to" + (l<"a" ? "Low" : "Upp") + "erCase"` which generates the function to call (make the string upper or lower case). We put this in square brackets `[ ... ]` which lets us access a property given its name as a string. This returns the appropriate function and then we just call it.

Comment: `/[A-Z]/gi` is a shorter regex :3

Comment: @KevinLau-notKenny oh nice catch, thanks!

Comment: `to${l<"a"?"Lower":"Upper"}Case` to `to${l<"a"?"Low":"Upp"}erCase`

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ oh nice, thanks!

Comment: ``l[`to${l<"a"?"Low":"Upp"}erCase`]()`` I think we have a new definition of evil.

Comment: That `toUpperCase()` trick is really clever. +1

Answer (score 10):

## Ruby, <s>37</s> 33 (30 +  `-p` flag) bytes

`swapcase` to the rescue! Sort of. -4 bytes from @Lynn.

```
gsub(/[a-z]/i){$&+$&.swapcase}
```

Comment: `gsub(/[a-z]/i){$&+$&.swapcase}` plus the `p` flag is 31 bytes.

Comment: @Lynn I believe consensus was edit difference needed from default script, so the `p` flag is `(space)-p` aka 3 bytes.

Answer (score 8):

## C, <s>63</s> 60 bytes

```
f(char*s){for(;*s;s++)isalpha(putchar(*s))&&putchar(32^*s);}
```

Uses the fact that `'a' XOR 32 == 'A'`, etc.

Three bytes saved thanks to FryAmTheEggman.

Comment: you can move the `s++` in the last `putchar` (`&&putchar(32^*s++)`)  to save [one byte](https://imgflip.com/readImage?iid=48526814)

Comment: I think you can replace `&&` with `*`, can't you?

Comment: I’m pretty sure both of those don’t work, if I think about how `&&`’s short-circuiting behaviour works.

Comment: `f(char*s){isalpha(putchar(*s))&&putchar(32^*s);*s&&f(1+s);}` recursive?

Comment: `f(char*s){*s&&f(1+s,isalpha(putchar(*s))&&putchar(32^*s));}` recursive?

Answer (score 6):

### CJam, 11 bytes

```
l_el_eu.+.|
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=l_el_eu.%2B.%7C&input=Ba%20d1!zzz)

#### Explanation

```
l      e# Read input.
_el    e# Duplicate, convert to lower case.
_eu    e# Duplicate, convert to upper case.
.+     e# Concatenate the two characters in matching positions from those two
       e# strings. E.g. "ab!" "AB!" would give ["aA" "bB" "!!"].
       e# For each character from the original string and the corresponding 
.|     e# string from this list, take the set union (which eliminates duplicates
       e# and keeps the order the values appear in from left to right, so that
       e# the original case of each letter comes first).
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 7 bytes

```
sm{+dr2
```

[Test suite](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=sm%7B%2Bdr2&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%22bad%22%0A%22Nice%22%0A%22T+e+S+t%22%0A%22s+E+t%22&debug=0).

```
sm{+dr2    input: Q
sm{+dr2dQ  implicit arguments

        Q  input
 m         for each character as d:
     r2d       swapcase
   +d          prepend d
  {            deduplicate
s          join as string
```

Comment: Haha, that's really fast :D

Answer (score 5):

## Python 3.5, <s>60</s> 56 bytes:

```
for i in input():print(end=i+i.swapcase()[:i.isalpha()])
```

A full program. Will try to golf more.

[Try It Online! (Ideone)](http://ideone.com/5j1h7y)

Answer (score 5):

## Haskell, 73 bytes

```
l=['a'..'z']
u=['A'..]
(>>= \c->c:maybe""pure(lookup c$zip l u++zip u l))
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Cheddar](http://cheddar.vihan.org), <s>118</s> 104 bytes

```
(s)->s.chars.map((i)->{if String.letters has i.lower{if i<"a"{i+i.lower}else{i+i.upper}}else{i}}).join()
```

First real Cheddar answer!!! This is a lot less climactic than I thought it would be... ;_;

Works with release [1.0.0-beta.9](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.9), non-competing.

---

As you can tell I didn't design cheddar to be golfy :/

Ungolfed:

```
(str) -> str.chars.map(
    (i) -> {
        if String.letters has i {
            if i < "a" { // Check char code, meaning it's upper case if true
                i+i.lower
            }
            else {
                i+i.upper
            }
        } else {
            i
        }
    }
).join()
```

Usage:

```
var doThing = <code here>;
doThing("input...");
```

---

**Update:** 7/14/16 I've finished ternaries making this come down to 84 bytes

### Cheddar, 84 bytes

```
(s)->s.chars.map((i)->String.letters has i.lower?i<"a"?i+i.lower:i+i.upper:i).join()
```

works as of version [v1.0.0-beta.14](https://github.com/cheddar-lang/Cheddar/releases/tag/v1.0.0-beta.14)

Comment: Yay! We've been waiting for this moment for a long time!

Comment: With one or two method name changes, is also valid [Sidef](https://github.com/trizen/sidef)

Comment: @cat o_o the similarity is unsettling

Comment: Well, they're both influenced by Perl, Perl 6, Ruby, Python, etc, so it's not that surprising :P

Comment: @cat oh no no no no no, cheddar was _not_ influenced by python

Comment: @Downgoat xD I meant JavaScript because Sidef wasn't influenced (much) by Python either -- more coffee pls

Comment: @Downgoat ewwwww python. Also I love these lambdas with implicit returns

Answer (score 4):

## Retina, <s>28</s> <s>27</s> 21 bytes

Those are tabs, not spaces.

```
.
$&  $&
T`lL    p`Ll_`  .
```

[**Try it online**](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LgokJgkkJgpUYGxMCXBgTGxfYAku&input=YmFkCk5pY2UKVCBlIFMgdApzIEUgdAoxITEhMXN0IQpuMDBiIAooZS5nLikKSDNsfEAh)

Thanks for the suggestions everyone.

Comment: The spaces are eaten by SE.

Comment: `[A-Za-z]` -> `i\`[A-Z]`

Comment: Martin and I were talking in chat, and we came up with: http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LgokJsK2JCYKVGBsTMK2cGBMbF9gwrYu&input=YmEgZDEhenp6

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Ah, I forgot about `_`. I'm going to use tabs so I can test all test cases at once, though.

Comment: You can build a test suite by using per-line mode and a group! http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAouCiQmwrYkJgpUYGxMwrZwYExsX2DCti4&input=YmFkCk5pY2UKVCBlIFMgdApzIEUgdAoxITEhMXN0IQpuMDBiIAooZS5nLikKSDNsfEAh

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Sure, but it's not golfed. :P

Comment: But the test suite doesn't have to be golfed :P Just leaving a note saying "the first line makes it run separately on each line" is usually good enough. Here, it would save you the craziness of tab characters.

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'm on Team Tabs. Sorry.

Answer (score 4):

## C, <s>87</s> 80

Pass a string as input to `f()` and the output is written to STDOUT. The string is not modified.

```
f(char*v){for(;*v;++v)putchar(*v),isalpha(*v)?putchar(*v-32+64*!islower(*v)):0;}
```

Comment: Can you provide a way to try it online?

Comment: @aloisdg Try http://ideone.com

Answer (score 4):

## sed, 30 bytes

29 bytes code + 1 byte parameter `-r`

```
s/([a-z])|([A-Z])/&\u\1\l\2/g
```

Usage:

```
echo -e 'bad\nNice\nT e S t\ns E t\n1!1!1st!\nn00b\n(e.g.)\nH3l|@!' |\
sed -r 's/([a-z])|([A-Z])/&\u\1\l\2/g'
```

Answer (score 4):

## Ruby, <s>31+1=32</s> 30+1=31 bytes

With the `-p` flag, run

```
gsub(/(?<=(.))/){$1.swapcase!}
```

Takes advantage of the fact that `swapcase!` will return `nil` on anything but an ASCII letter, which translates to an empty string when returned out of the `gsub` block. @Jordan saved a byte by capturing the previous character in a look-behind.

Comment: Matching with `//` and then using ``$`[-1]`` is clever.

Comment: I managed to shave off six bytes with lookbehind: `gsub(/(?<=(.))/){$1.swapcase!}`. Same basic concept, though, so feel free to use it.

Comment: Cool! That looks one byte shorter to me.

Comment: Er, yes, one byte. I think I had some extra code in there to test that I accidentally counted.

Comment: There is no need to use the self-modifying version of `.swapcase!`. (I mean, remove the `!`.)

Comment: No, that part's still necessary to avoid duplicating non-alphabet characters.

Answer (score 4):

## J, <s>31</s> 29 bytes

```
[:;]<@~."1@,.tolower,.toupper
```

### Explanation

```
[:;]<@~."1@,.tolower,.toupper  Input: s
                      toupper  Convert s to all uppercase
             tolower           Convert s to all lowercase
                    ,.         Join them as columns in a 2d array
   ]                           Identity function, get s
           ,.                  Prepend s as a column to the 2d array
      ~."1@                    Take the unique chars on each row
    <@                         Box them
[:;                            Unbox the list of boxes and join their contents and return
```

Answer (score 4):

## Haskell, <s>121, 101, 85,</s> 82

```
import Data.Char
g n|isLower n=toUpper n|1<2=toLower n
(>>= \x->x:[g x|isAlpha x])
```

Comment: By replacing the if-then-else by guards, you can save 15 bytes or so. And `isLower` is shorter than the construct with `elem`, for 5 bytes more.

Comment: `>>=` is `concatMap` (or `concat.map`) with arguments flipped: `f n = n >>= (\x->if isAlpha x then[x,r x]else[x])`. You can go pointfree and omit the function name and replace the definition of `f` with `(>>= \x->if isAlpha x then[x,r x]else[x])`.

Comment: Instead of `otherwise` you can use any expression that evaluates to `True`, e.g. `1<2`. You can replace the `if .. then .. else` with a list comprehension: `\x->[x]++[g x|isAlpha x]`. Oh, and there's a bug: the second `toUpper` in `g` must be a `toLower`.

Comment: Oh, one more: `[x]++` is `x:`.

Answer (score 4):

### Perl, 36 bytes (35 + `-n` flag)

```
s/[a-z]/$&.(ord$&<97?lc$&:uc$&)/ige
```

(`-p` tag needed)

(-2 bytes thanks to @Dom Hasting)

Short explanation:
`ord` returns the numeric value of a char. `ord(any lower case) >= 97`, and `ord(any upper case) <= 90)`.

Run with :

```
perl -pe 's/[a-z]/$&.(ord$&<97?lc$&:uc$&)/ige'
```

Comment: You still need to use `/i` or your regexp will match several codepoints between letters.

Comment: @OlegV.Volkov oh right, thanks, answer edited.

Comment: Got it down one more byte, using your method: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YNTpRtypWVUMl3lZFTVNPw9LcLr8oxT4n2ao0WVM1Mz31//@SjMxiBc9ihUSFktTikn/5BSWZ@XnF/3V9TfUMDA3@6xYAAA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## R, <strike>191</strike> <strike>187</strike> <s>168</s> <s>156</s> <s>98</s> 99 bytes

99 bytes due to improvements fro [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/67312/giuseppe) and [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31347/mickyt).

```
paste0(x<-unlist(strsplit(readline(),"")),gsub("[^A-Za-z]","",chartr("a-zA-Z","A-Za-z",x)),collapse="")
```

Comment: [98 bytes](https://tio.run/##JctBCsJADIXhu2SVgZniAXThNRSFdAxtIdohidB6@THi4m2@x69dllFJd3yyz@vDUm9kzgfcjoUFzdWaLI5W6YUZIP2W8mTvEeF6P5cLlc8NQnOdSV0RAoKD/ifkLYK6ilAzPkXekYdpSP0L) -- maybe sometime next year, we can find another golf of this, hahaha.

Comment: I hate to be the bearer of bad new, but it fails on test cases with spaces.  `readline()` can be used, but it will cost a byte

Comment: @MickyT thanks, fixed now.

Comment: @MickyT `scan` will work with input given wrapped in quotes (as is often the case for command-line arguments in other languages)

Comment: @Giuseppe Sorry I didn't realise that.  I just thought it automatically split on whitespace unless you specify a non whitespace character.  Sorry rturnbull

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Code:

```
vyyš«Ù?
```

Explanation:

```
v       # For each in input.
 yyš    # Push y and y swapcased.
    «Ù  # Concatentate and uniquify.
      ? # Print without a newline.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=dnl5xaHCq8OZPw&input=TiBpIEMgZQ)

Comment: Maybe you could provide a link to the interpreter?

Comment: @nicael It IS linked... It's right there on github.

Comment: So no online interpreter? :(

Comment: @nicael Then download it, and run it. There doesn't have to be an *online* interpreter, just an interpreter.

Comment: @nicael Yeah, there is no online interpreter available yet :(. The offline version should work though.

Comment: @mbo I'm not saying it *doesn't*, I was just wondering if there is one. Neither I was implying that the off-line interpreters are bad.

Answer (score 3):

### Pyke, <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
FDl4+}
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=FDl4%2B%7D&input=%28e.g.%29)

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 21 bytes

[Try it online!](http://v.tryitonline.net/#code=w5MuL8Kww7IKw43DoS_CsMKwCsOObGd-bMOOSMOyZ0o&input=SDNsfEAh)

Too many bytes...

```
Ó./°ò
Íá/°°
Îlg~lÎHògJ
```

Answer (score 3):

### Actually, 8 bytes

```
`;Öo╔`MΣ
```

[Try it online!](http://actually.tryitonline.net/#code=YDvDlm_ilZRgTc6j&input=IkgzbHxAISI)

Explanation:

```
`;Öo╔`MΣ
`;Öo╔`M   for each character in input:
 ;          duplicate the character
  Ö         swap case
   o        append to original character
    ╔       remove duplicated characters
       Σ  concatenate
```

Answer (score 3):

## MATL, <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
tYov"@uv!
```

[**Try it Online**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=dFlvdiJAdXYh&input=J0gzbHxAISc)

**Explanation**

```
        % Implicitly grab input as string
t       % Duplicate the input
Yo      % Swap case of all characters
v       % Vertically concatenate the original and swap-cased versions
"       % For each column (letter in the original)
  @u    % Compute the unique values (without sorting)
  v!    % Vertically concatenate with the existing output and transpose
        % Implicit end of for loop and implicit display
```

Answer (score 3):

### Common Lisp (Lispworks), 262 bytes

```cl
(defun f(s)(let((b""))(dotimes(i(length s))(if(lower-case-p(elt s i))(progn #1=(setf b(concatenate 'string b(string #2=(elt s i))))(setf b(concatenate 'string b(string(char-upcase #2#)))))(progn #1#(setf b(concatenate 'string b(string(char-downcase #2#)))))))b))
```

ungolfed:

```cl
(defun f (s)
  (let ((b ""))
    (dotimes (i (length s))
      (if (lower-case-p (elt s i))
          (progn
           #1=(setf b (concatenate 'string b (string #2=(elt s i))))
           (setf b (concatenate 'string b (string (char-upcase #2#)))))
        (progn
          #1#
          (setf b (concatenate 'string b (string (char-downcase #2#)))))))
    b))
```

Usage:

```cl
CL-USER 1 > (f "abc")
"aAbBcC"

CL-USER 2 > (f "bad")
"bBaAdD"
```

Comment: This might be smaller if the input is `coerce`d into a list and `append` is used instead of `(concatenate 'string ...)`

Comment: Invalid because It duplicates spaces. :r

Comment: You can `(coerce (apply 'nconc (map...` over string where map collects a list of list of chars. I reduced it to 162 bytes [Try It Online](http://shorturl.at/wxy58)

Answer (score 3):

### Perl, <s>28</s> <s>22</s> 21 bytes (20 + `-p` flag)

```
s/[a-z]/$&.$&^$"/ige
```

Comment: I imagine you can save a byte by using `$"` instead of `' '`, but I haven't tested.

Comment: @msh210, nice! How could I forget to check perlvar for default strings? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure if it's a version change or something, but it seems `.` has higher precedence than `^` resulting in slightly wrong output, but you can combine `\K` and capturing match for the 19 bytes and valid output: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXyOmIEczxltfxTBORUk/Mz31//88A4MkRcV/@QUlmfl5xf91CwA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Comment: Just realised you don't need to `/i` any more with `\pl` for another -1!

Answer (score 3):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), <s>7</s> 6 bytes

Thanks to @recursive for a byte saved!

```
┤§ÆP♦■
```

[Run and debug it at staxlang.xyz!](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=c%3A~%5C%7Bum&i=%22bad%22%0A%0A%22Nice%22%0A%0A%22T+e+S+t%22%0A%0A%22s+E+t%22%0A%0A%221%211%211st%21%22%0A%0A%22n00b+%22+%0A++%0A%22%28e.g.%29%22%0A%0A%22H3l%7C%40%21%22%0A%0A%22123%22%0A&a=1&m=1) (link is to unpacked version)

#### Unpacked (7 bytes):

```
c:~\{um
```

#### Explanation:

```
c:~\{um
c          Copy the top element of the stack (the input, in this case).
 :~        Switch case of each letter in the copy.
   \       Zip. This produces an array of two-character strings.
    { m    Map a block over this array of two-character strings.
     u       Get all unique elements.
           Implicit concatenate and print.
```

Comment: Thanks for giving stax a try.  One easy improvement you can make is to use `u` instead of `:g`.  It will get all the unique elements in an array, which is exactly what you want in this case.  Other than that, this looks well golfed.

Comment: @recursive Thanks! Forgot about that one :/ Will edit in soon.

Comment: Doesn't work for `123`. You may need to change the format for all inputs (i.e. quote them). The link is also broken. You need to replace `m=11` with `m=2`. There is a PPCG post generating button on staxlang.xyz so you may want to use that one.

Comment: @WeijunZhou Thanks, fixed!

Answer (score 2):

### Python, 59 bytes

```
lambda s:''.join((x,x+x.swapcase())[x.isalpha()]for x in s)
```

Edited to fix repeating non-alphabetic characters

Answer (score 2):

## Julia, 40 bytes

```julia
!s=[print(c,isalpha(c)?c$' ':"")for c=s]
```

[Try it online!](http://julia.tryitonline.net/#code=IXM9W3ByaW50KGMsaXNhbHBoYShjKT9jJCcgJzoiIilmb3IgYz1zXQoKZm9yIHMgaW4gKCJiYWQiLCAiTmljZSIsICJUIGUgUyB0IiwgInMgRSB0IiwgIjEhMSExc3QhIiwgIm4wMGIiLCAiKGUuZy4pIiwgIkgzbHxAISIpCiAgICBAcHJpbnRmKCIlLTExcyIscykKICAgICFzCiAgICBwcmludGxuKCkKZW5k&input=)

Comment: `not s is (list comprehension)` okay, Julia...

Answer (score 2):

## C#, <s>82</s> 71 bytes

```
s=>string.Concat(s.Select(c=>c+(char.IsLetter(c)?(char)(c^32)+"":"")));
```

C# lambda where the input and the output are `string`. [Try it online](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Gti6h7).

11 bytes thanks to @Lynn trick.

Answer (score 2):

## PHP 4.1, 57 bytes

This code assumes access through a web server (Apache, for example), using the default configuration.

You can pass the string by sending the key `S` by any means (`POST`, `GET`, `COOKIE`, `SESSION`...).

```
<?for($i=0;$c=$S[$i++];)echo$c,ctype_alpha($c)?$c^' ':'';
```

Answer (score 2):

## Java 8, <s>105</s> <s>104</s> 80 bytes

```java
a->{for(char c:a)System.out.print(c+(c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?(char)(c^32)+"":""));}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##nY5Ba8IwGIbv/RWfOYwEMVg7BO3WbYzBLutFb@Lg69fo6mpakiiI9rd3sfM0diqBkC/J877PDo84qmqld/l3SyVaCx9Y6HMAUGinzAZJQXodAY5VkQNx@kKzWgOK2N82gd@sQ1cQpKDhEVocJedNZbp/QHMUi5N1ai@rg5O18amchpyS6f0dPczCCyWzqT@Fk@ipQwSnz2gihozNGRMibtr42lEfstJ33Ko6lb0X5QvnI7erNYpfSS2JswxzJl316uNejMETF50swF@VUvPbS8elBale4BIULMD1Yi289STDgV/WDXrBejzOeoFcya0UvdD3qLw8/6vbBE37Aw)

```java
a->{                          // Method with character-array parameter and no return-type
  for(char c:a)               //  For each character in the input:
    System.out.print(c        //   Print the current character
     +(c>64&c<91|c>96&c<123?  //   And if it's a letter:
       (char)(c^32)+""        //    Print the letter again with reversed case
      :                       //   Else:
       ""));}                 //    Print nothing more
```

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL, 244

The byte total includes a one-byte string.  Replace the example input string "Q" with the string you want to try.

```
DECLARE @I VARCHAR(MAX)='Q',@O VARCHAR(MAX)='',@ CHAR #:SELECT @=LEFT(@I,1),@O+=@+CASE WHEN @ LIKE'[A-Za-z]'COLLATE Thai_BIN THEN CASE WHEN ASCII(@)/13IN(5,6)THEN LOWER(@)ELSE UPPER(@)END ELSE''END,@I=STUFF(@I,1,1,'')IF LEN(@I)>0GOTO # PRINT @O
```

This script works in SQL Server 2008 R2, although you can try it in SQL Server 2016 [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/615597).  This SQL works by iterating through the characters in the input string @I, checking each character using a short-named collation and ASCII codes.  When one character is processed, the result is added to the output string @O and removed from @I.

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 8 bytes

```
r\lÈ+c^H
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=2.0a0&code=clxsyCtjXkg=&input=IlQgZSBTIHQi)

---

### Explanation

```
r            :Replace
 \l          :Regex /[a-z]/gi
   È         :Pass each match X through a function
    +        :  Append
    c        :  The charcode of X
     ^       :  Bitwise XORed
       H     :  With 32
```

Answer (score 2):

## [str](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/str), 6 bytes

```
d#S:#q
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky4p@v8/RTnYSrnw//@kxBQuv8zkVK4QhVSFYIUSrmIFVyBpqAiExSWKXHkGBklcGql66XqaXB7GOTUOigA)

### Explanation

```
d#S:#q
          over each character:
d         duplicate
 #S       swapcase
   :      concatenate
    #q    uniq-ify string
```

Answer (score 1):

### C, 62 bytes

Function that reads from `stdin` and writes to `stdout`:

```
f(c){while(c=getchar())printf(isalpha(c)?"%c%c":"%c",c,c^32);}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Erlang, 106 bytes

```
f(S)->G=string,lists:flatten([case G:to_upper(C)==G:to_lower(C)of true->C;false->[C,C bxor 32]end||C<-S]).
```

Uses [Lynn's XOR trick](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84965/21777) to toggle the case.

Answer (score 1):

## Gema, 37 characters

```
<J>=$1@upcase{$1}
<K>=$1@downcase{$1}
```

Sample run:

```
bash-4.3$ gema '<J>=$1@upcase{$1};<K>=$1@downcase{$1}' <<< 'H3l|@!'
Hh3lL|@!
```

Answer (score 1):

## PowerShell, 102 Bytes

```
-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{$_;if($_-cmatch'[A-Z]'){"$_".ToLower()}if($_-cmatch'[a-z]'){"$_".ToUpper()}})
```

Run the script with an argument like so:

```
PS C:\PretendDirectory> .\DupeCase.ps1 "Hello World ?!!1"
HheElLlLoO WwoOrRlLdD ?!!1
```

Ungolfed:

```
-join([char[]]$args[0] | % {
    $_
    if($_-cmatch'[A-Z]'){
        "$_".ToLower()
    }
    if($_-cmatch'[a-z]'){
        "$_".ToUpper()
    }
})
```

Explanation:

This script splits the argument from a string into a character array, and loops through the array. It returns a given character then, if it's an upper case letter between A and Z returns a lowercase version using the built in function, does the same for lowercase letters. To wrap up it joins the array into a single string.

Comment: If you go with v3 or higher for the `-in` operator, you can exploit the fact that `char` and `int` can implicitly cast back and forth and use string multiplication instead of `if`s to cut it down to 88 -- `-join([char[]]$args[0]|%{$_;"$_".ToLower()*($_-in65..90)+"$_".ToUpper()*($_-in97..122)})`

Answer (score 1):

## Rust, 250 bytes

```
fn main(){let(mut i,mut o)=(String::new(),String::new());std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut i);let b:&[u8]=i.trim().as_bytes();for x in b{o.push(*x as char);if*x>64&&*x<91{o.push((x+32)as char)}else if*x>96&&*x<123{o.push((x-32)as char)}}print!("{}",o)}
```

Ungolfed

```
fn main() {
    let (mut input_string, mut output_string) = (String::new(), String::new());
    std::io::stdin().read_line(&mut input_string);
    let bytes: &[u8] = input_string.trim().as_bytes();

    for x in bytes {
        output_string.push(*x as char);
        if *x > 64 && *x < 91 {
            //is_uppercase
            output_string.push((x + 32) as char);
        } else if *x > 96 && *x < 123 {
            //is_lowercase
            output_string.push((x - 32) as char);
        }
    }
    print!("{}", output_string);
}
```

This answer assumes the input only consists of ASCII characters. It uses comparisons and addition/subtraction instead of library functions as it is shorter.

Answer (score 1):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 100 bytes

```
D,g,@,O91 65r$e
D,l,@,O123 97r$eBn
D,w,@~,S
D,f,@~,€gB]VAbU€lB]GBcB+32€*B]VAbU€OB]GBcB+€CJABc€wB@B+J
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99FJ13HQcff0lDBzLRIJZXLRScHxDc0MlawNAcKOOUBhcp1HOp0goGMNBDjUdOadKfYMMekUCArxynW3SnZSdvYCMjRggv7Q4WBTGcvR6dkIF3u5OCk7fX//391Q0UgLC5RVP@XX1CSmZ9X/F9XNzO3ICczObMEyCwuSE3OTKu0TQMA)

This is annoyingly long. Let's compare this answer to the current shortest, Dennis' [Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84945/66833):

```
żŒsQ€
```

Here, I've split it into three parts: **`ż`**, *`Œs`* and ***`Q€`***, highlighted to show the corresponding parts in the Add++ code, as so:

```
D,g,@,O91 65r$e
D,l,@,O123 97r$eBn
D,w,@~,S
D,f,@~,€gB]VAbU€lB]GBcB+32€*B]VAbU€OB]GBcB+€CJABc€wB@B+J
```

### How it works

```
		; A note on functions:
		; Each function returns the value on the top of the stack
		; A function has 'flags' that change its behaviour:
		;
		;	@	-	Specifies an argument to be taken
		;	~	-	Splats the arguments to the stack

D,u,@,		; Declare a monadic function 'u'
		; Example argument:	['I']
	O	; Ordinal;	STACK = [73]
	91 65r	; [65 ... 90];	STACK = [73 [65 66 ... 89 90]]
	$e	; Contains?	STACK = [1]

D,l,@,		; Declare a monadic function 'l'
		; Example argument:	['i']
	O	; Ordinal;	STACK = [105]
	123 97r	; [97 ... 122];	STACK = [105 [97 98 ... 121 122]]
	$e	; Contains?	STACK = [1]
	Bn	; Negate;	STACK = [-1]

D,w,@~,		; Declare a monadic function 'w'
		; Example argument:	[['N' 'n']]
	S	; Deduplicate;	STACK = [['N' 'n']]

D,f,@~,		; Declare a monadic function 'f'
		; Example argument:		['N' 'i' 'c' 'e' '!']
	€u	; Map 'u' over €ach;	STACK = [1 0 0 0 0]
	B]	; Wrap the stack;	STACK = [[1 0 0 0 0]]
	V	; Save;			STACK = []
	AbU	; Push argument;	STACK = ['N' 'i' 'c' 'e' '!']
	€l	; Map 'l' over €ach;	STACK = [0 -1 -1 -1 0]
	B]	; Wrap;			STACK = [[0 -1 -1 -1 0]]
	G	; Retrieve;		STACK = [[0 -1 -1 -1 0] [1 0 0 0 0]]
	BcB+	; Column sums;		STACK = [1 -1 -1 -1 0]
	32€*	; Multiply €ach by 32;	STACK = [32 -32 -32 -32 0]
	B]	; Wrap;			STACK = [[32 -32 -32 -32 0]]
	V	; Save;			STACK = []
	AbU€OB]	; Codepoints of input;	STACK = [[78 105 99 101 33]]
	G	; Retrieve;		STACK = [[78 105 99 101 33] [32 -32 -32 -32 0]]
	BcB+	; Column sums;		STACK = [110 73 67 69 33]
	€C	; Convert to chars;	STACK = ['n' 'I' 'C' 'E' '!']
	JABc	; Zip with argument;	STACK = [['n' 'N'] ['I' 'i'] ['C' 'c'] ['E' 'e'] ['!' '!']]
	€w	; Map 'w' over €ach;	STACK = [['n' 'N'] ['I' 'i'] ['C' 'c'] ['E' 'e'] ['!']]
	B@	; Reverse each;		STACK = [['N' 'n'] ['i' 'I'] ['c' 'C'] ['e' 'E'] ['!']]
	B+	; Sum each;		STACK = ['Nn' 'iI' 'cC' 'eE' '!']
	J	; Join;			STACK = ['NniIcCeE!']
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), <s>87</s> 86 bytes

```
x->x.map{c->if(c.isLetter())"$c${(c.toInt()xor 32).toChar()}" else c}.joinToString("")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU7LasMwELz7K9bCBwlqkTa3QE0hBFoo7SH5AUWVHDWKFKRtMKj6dnebZJZlZh/M7jGid2G2PwFOygV@UUmlESjzCraYXBgFlAYI3mX8tJzt1Rd7YB9OG6IdGNgCksqwufJjS5GxJRkWiz0RN3KUgsTr0v@@tExIG9NG6cPd@B9nuoQ@cNY5hH6ArljuUFQmriu1qU1zUR7sit@/6oebeC7NPPXDJE/qXHQ/OMu1dPndIJrEhWCd7gq1ML4F5GKKCZZPgsr1QdG8MjA@G9BVfkcXdvHmyhkTc53/AA)

I wish Kotlin had a ternary operator, but it doesn't so I'm stuck with the more verbose if/else.

I feel like I can get this shorter if I can find a way to consolidate map{} and joinToString() in one call.

Answer (score 1):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), 139 bytes

```
	U =&UCASE
	L =&LCASE
	I =INPUT
S	I LEN(1) . X REM . I	:F(O)
	X ANY(L U)	:S(D)F(A)
D	X =X REPLACE(X,L U,U L)
A	O =O X	:(S)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY3BCsIwEETPu1@xXmQXiiB6KgQMTYqFmBTTQLx6Lvbg1X@PK57m8WZg3q/tua3n1qCQ2ZfBZo8QFMMfJzJTnMuCWTH4yEehA1W6@5vmBP3ISRAq2fjgQEWgz@xkZCvoVJvfdA528Fw77btCQdBCIpOoQs9ZMEEqi36oQh8dtHY9rZ/L7gs)

The line `X ANY(L U)     :S(D)F(A)` checks if any of `X` are `U`pper or `L`owercase, going to `D` if so or to `A` if not. Then `D` duplicates and swaps case, and `A` concatenates the results together, finally outputting once `I` has no characters.

Comment: Looks like this challenge is still getting some attention and I am not sure how to revive it since there're already really short answers which are difficult to outgolf. :)

Comment: @nicael there are always more languages! This is a really good challenge, and I've taken the perspective that code golf is trying to find the shortest answer in each language!

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `d`, 5 bytes

```
ƛǍ[N"
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=d&code=%C6%9B%C7%8D%5BN%22&inputs=%28bad%29&header=&footer=)

```
ƛ     # Map to...
 Ǎ[   # If alphabetical
   N" # Pair with swap_case
      # (Otherwise leave it)
      # (d flag) Print deep sum of stack
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java, 259 bytes

```
for (i=0;i<in.length();i++)
{
if(Character.isLowerCase(in.charAt(i))){
o=o+in.charAt(i)+Character.toUpperCase(in.charAt(i));}
else if(Character.isUpperCase(in.charAt(i))){o=o+in.charAt(i)+Character.toLowerCase(in.charAt(i));}
else {o=o+in.charAt(i);}}
```

Comment: This is the code golf, your answer should be as short as possible (and defintely lack any excess spacing, tabbing, etc). Also you should include the length of your code in bytes.

Comment: @nicael , I edited. Is it OK ?

Comment: I've removed other whitespace and newlines.

Comment: Also, [just a useful post](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/6671/tips-for-golfing-in-java) :)

Comment: @nicael Unlike Stack Overflow and other SE sites, please don't edit others' answers, even if you are the OP. it's up to them.

Comment: @cat Okay, sorry for that! I have edited not because of being the question OP, but just because wanted to help the new user.

Answer (score 0):

## [Yabasic](http://www.yabasic.de), 133 bytes

A [yabasic](/questions/tagged/yabasic) answer that takes input as a raw string and outputs to the STDOUT.

```vb
Line Input""S$
For i=1To Len(S$)
c$=Mid$(S$,i,1)
u$=Upper$(c$)
?c$;
If"@"<u$And u$<"["Then
If c$=u$Then?Lower$(c$);Else?u$;Fi
Fi
Next
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LYuxCoMwFEX3fMXj8QYFF@cotkMFIe2SdOpk4ysNSBRNaPv1aQqFO9x7Lucz3sfd2ZSU8wyDX2NA1CT6ZQPX1mYBxb7QVApL7dlNlHvlqroUkdrruvJGhc1vZ0mK4YEHbCId/QSRGryhebLPGLIc6Tc6tbz@jjzNO3eRZO9EzoXfISUDDBrCFw)

Answer (score 0):

## x86-16 machine code, IBM PC DOS, 26 bytes

**Binary:**

```
00000000: b401 cd21 3c61 7c08 3c7a 7ff4 24df eb06  ...!<a|.<z..$...
00000010: 3c41 7cec 0c20 cd29 ebe6                 <A|.. .)..
```

**Unassembled listing:**

```
        START: 
B4 01       MOV  AH, 1                  ; DOS read char from STDIN 
CD 21       INT  21H                    ; read char into AL
3C 61       CMP  AL, 'a'                ; is letter < ASCII 'a'? 
7C 08       JL   UPPER                  ; if so, check if uppercase 
3C 7A       CMP  AL, 'z'                ; is letter > ASCII 'z'? 
7F F4       JG   START                  ; if so, don't repeat 
24 DF       AND  AL, NOT ('A' XOR 'a')  ; uppercase it 
EB 06       JMP  WRITE                  ; continue to display
        UPPER: 
3C 41       CMP  AL, 'A'                ; is letter < ASCII 'Z'? 
7C EC       JL   START                  ; if so, don't repeat either 
0C 20       OR   AL, 'A' XOR 'a'        ; lowercase it 
        WRITE: 
CD 29       INT  29H                    ; write AL to screen 
EB E6       JMP  START                  ; keep looping
```

Standalone IBM PC DOS executable.  Input via `STDIN`, output to console.

**I/O:**

[image]